# How to create a completely custom query in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

### Request

Within spring boot I'd like to run a **completely custom** query, for example running a query to get the firstname and lastname columns on the table person. BUT where the existence of the table person and the fact that it may have columns firstname and lastname was not known at compile time.

### Why I want to do this

I want to do this as within our application because we have a concept of custom fields and custom entities. These have views automatically built over the top of them. At run time I will know what views are available and what columns they have but I will not know that when the application starts (and they may change while the application is running

### What I don't want

A query annotation on a crudRepository because that still needs to target a particular object and so can't have dynamic fields or an arbitrary object (unless someone knows how to make a crudRepository do that)

Comment: So just run plain JDBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have knowledge of the entity and the fields you need at run time, you can use SpringJDBC Templates to construct SQL queries. Below is an example of fetching a `Todo` item. You can do something similar but passing in the entity name and a collection of fields you would want. Here is a very basic example:

```
@Autowired 
private DataSource dataSource; // Configure this in a class annotated with @Configuration

public Todo fetchWithToDoId(long id) {
    Todo record = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).queryForObject("SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.TODO WHERE todo_id = ?", new Object[]{id}, getRowMapper());
    return record;
}

private RowMapper<Todo> getRowMapper() {
    return (resultSet, i) -> {
        Todo d = new Todo();
        d.setUserId(resultSet.getInt("todo_user_id"));
        d.setId(resultSet.getInt("todo_id"));
        d.setTitle(resultSet.getString("todo_title"));
        d.setCompleted(resultSet.getBoolean("todo_completed"));
        d.setCreated(resultSet.getTimestamp("todo_created"));
        return d;
    };
}
```

If the tables and the columns do not exist then an exception will be thrown and it's up to you to handle them on the server side and present the appropriate view to the client. You would probably expand this to take in as argument an entity and a KeyValuePair data structure to map field to value. When you construct you query then it will present all the fields and their target values.

Comment: Your JdbcTemplate is taking a datasource, where did that come from?

Comment: You will need to autowire a `datasource` bean into you class. You can read the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Comment: Your comment "Configure this in a class annotated with @Configuration" doesn't seem to be necessary, it seems to grab springs existing data access, which was my primary objective, not to set up completely parallel data access but to hook into springs